# How to send information to a ScrolledText from a form in Tkinter with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I made a form in Tkinter but when it is anwered I need the information to concatenate to a textbox.

Let's say I select I live in Chicago, how do I send that information to the scrolled text when I press the button "send"?

```
   lblCd= Label(ventana,text="Location:",font= ("Arial", 20), 
   fg="blue", bg="white").place(x=70,y=400)
   combo['values']=("Chicago","NY", "Texas")
   combo.current(1)
   combo.place(x=260, y=400)


    Btn=Button(ventana, text="Send",)
    Btn.place(x=200,y=500)

    txt=scrolledtext.ScrolledText(ventana, width=40, height=10) 
    txt.place(x=260, y= 550)
    txt.insert(INSERT, Nombre)
```

Comment: `Button(..., command=function_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Button(..., command=function_name)` to execute `function_name()` when you press button. This function can get selected value and insert in scrolledtext.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext

def send_data():
    txt.insert('end', combo.get() + '\n')

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Location:")
label.pack()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=("Chicago","NY", "Texas"))
combo.pack()
combo.current(0)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Send", command=send_data)
button.pack()

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root) 
txt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thak you It worked! How can I do the same but with a checkbox? 

        #Checkbox
        def movies():
            print("Action:%d,\n Comedy:%d" % (var1.get(), var2.get()))
    
        var1=IntVar()
        b=Checkbutton(ventana, text="Action", variable=var1)
        b.place(x=200, y= 300)

        var2=IntVar()
        a=Checkbutton(ventana, text="Comedy", variable=var2)
        a.place(x=260, y= 300)

Comment: you can get `var1.get()` and `var2.get()` and `insert()` to scrolledtext.